# Double entries appearing when adding custom attribute to orders grid

Tags: orders, adminhtml, custom-attributes

I have added a few custom columns to the sales order grid.

SKU and product name were successfully added, appearing as expected in their respective rows.

Now when I add a product attribute that doesn't come from the sales_flat_order_item table, I get double entries populating for every row for these columns.

**=> For example :** I add custom_attr from the catalog_product_entity_varchar table. Now all three extra columns are doubled up:

**SKU: 123,123**

**Name: example, example**

**custom_attr: blue,blue**

I think the problem comes from the following code in my Observer, if anyone can spot it?

```
    $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $select->joinLeft(array('payment' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', array('payment_method' => 'method'));
    $select->join('m_sales_flat_order_item', '`m_sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('sku' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`m_sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")'),'name'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`m_sales_flat_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ", ")') ));
    $select->join('m_catalog_product_entity_varchar', '`m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.attribute_id=163 AND `m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.entity_id = `m_sales_flat_order_item`.`product_id`', array('custom_attr'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.value SEPARATOR ",")')));
    $select->group('main_table.entity_id');
```

**Update**

Thanks to the below responses I was able to reach a solution with a bit modification. The two joins worked as below.

```
    $select->join('m_sales_flat_order_item','`m_sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('sku' => new Zend_Db_Expr('`m_sales_flat_order_item`.sku'),'name'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('`m_sales_flat_order_item`.name') ))->where('`m_sales_flat_order_item`.parent_item_id IS NULL');
    $select->join(array('m_catalog_product_entity_varchar'),'(m_catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id = `m_sales_flat_order_item`.`product_id`) AND `m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.attribute_id=163',
array('custom_attr' => 'm_catalog_product_entity_varchar.value'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@snevet,you need add a condition to collection.

```
$select->where('`m_sales_flat_order_item`.parent_item_id IS NULL');
```

Because of when an configurable is ordered,two row insert into sales_flat_item table.**One is save  simple product id and another configurable product,but tow save same sku which is simple product sku**

Comment: Hello Amit, where should I put this in relation to the other lines of code?

Comment: $select->join('m_sales_flat_order_item', '`m_sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('sku' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`m_sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")'),'name'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`m_sales_flat_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ", ")') ))->where('`sales_flat_order_item`.parent_item_id IS NULL');;

Comment: I have tried this but nothing changes. The double entries remain. When I remove  the line starting $select->join('m_catalog_product_entity_varchar'... it gives me the correct entries for sku and name but of course a blank custom_attr column

Answer (score 1):

Try out below below code instead of custom_attr join:

```
->joinLeft(
    array('m_catalog_product_entity_varchar'),
    '(m_catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id = `m_sales_flat_order_item`.`product_id`) AND `m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.attribute_id=163',
    array('custom_attr' => m_catalog_product_entity_varchar.value)
)
```

Comment: I get the error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '`m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.value' in 'field list'

Comment: I had to modify your code a bit, but it allowed me to show the custom_attr column with the required output. But then the sku and name were still giving me the double entries. I'll update my question to show the final code. Thanks